# Generate report from cobertura with out J-Unit tasks

Tags: cobertura

My project do not have Junit and would prefer manual testing for code coverage testing.
I have instrumented the code using ant and i have it as an ear.
How i will configure the same in a weblogic1034 and how to take report after manual testing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions in the manual](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#running-tests) are fairly straightforward: if you instrumneted your classes directly into the EAR file, make sure to also include the cobertura.jar into the EAR file as well (under the 'lib/' sub-folder within the archive).

Then deploy your app and start it up normally. When you perform manual testing, a (cobertura).ser file will be  produced in the working directory of your app server instance.

Upon completion of your testing, you must shutdown your app server and make sure the JVM exits in order to flush the coverage data to the .ser file.

Finally convert the .ser file into a report [using ant](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference#cobertura-report-task) or the [command-line utility](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#reporting).